# Custom function in Google spreadsheet to calculate disagreement between two people

Tags: javascript, math, google-sheets

I'd like to create a custom function in Google spreadsheet (so javascript is is) to measure the level of disagreement between people who answered a survey.

Here is what I wrote:

```
function disagree(DISAG,otherMember) {
  var otherMember = '';
  var indivDisag = DISAG.localeCompare(otherMember);
  return Math.abs(indivDisag);
}
```

The localCompare should allow me to easily get 0 (if similar) or 1 (if different), but I keep getting 1. What did I mess up?

With this basic formula, I can check the disagreement of one person with another one.

edited for clarification

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please clarify what are you looking for? As it stands, it seems there's several questions involved: (1) why does the function you present always return `1`, (2) how to implement the disagreement formula you present, and (3) how to pass a cell range as an argument to a function.

Comment: Thanks, I left only the first question and will post another question for the other part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, considering that you always set `otherMember` to `''`, I think it is expected that there's always a difference. Why don't you try:

```
function disagree(DISAG, otherMember) {
  return Math.abs(DISAG.localeCompare(otherMember));
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the question if your satisfied.

Comment: Done, thanks. Following your advice, I posted the second part of the problem in a dedicated question. Would be great if you could give it a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444401/custom-function-in-google-spreadsheet-disagreement-between-one-person-and-rest/25450734#25450734