# Custom function in Google Spreadsheet: disagreement between one person and rest of the group

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I need to calculate the disagreement between respondents of a survey.

The first step was to calculate the disagreement between two respondents

```
function disagree(DISAG, otherMember) { 
  return Math.abs(DISAG.localeCompare(otherMember));
}
```

The second step is to calculate the average disagreement between one respondent and all the others.

To to so manually, I have to do:

```
1/(N-1) * (disagree(DISAG, otherMember) + disagree(DISAG, othermember2)) etc
```

To try to do it in one go, I wrote the following function, as a test

```
function TEST(DISAG) { 

 var otherMembers = ["No problem", "Can improve", "Can improve"]
 var indivDisag = []
 var sum = 0     

 for (var i in otherMembers) { 
  indivDisag[i] = DISAG.localeCompare(otherMembers[i])
 };

 for (var i in indivDisag) { 
  sum +=  Math.abs(indivDisag[i]); 
 };

  return sum / indivDisag.length

}
```

EDIT: My original issue was due to a typo. I now get a number returned in the spreadsheet, but whatever the value of DISAG, the number is always the same. It must be that I didn't interpret the math correctly when coding the function.

The math look like this:

```
d(i,j) = disagreement of an individual (i) with another (j).
if i == j, then d(i,j) = 0. if i != j then d(i,j) = 1

di = average agreement of one person with the rest of the group.

di = 1/(N-1) * SUM( d(i,j)*f(j) )

where N = number of people who answered the survey
and f(j) is a function of the different individual disagreements.
```

In plain English : the average agreement of one person is the result of the sum of her individual agreements divided by the number of pairs possible in the group (N-1).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points

I don't link google script knows what localCompare() is.
So if you fix this it will think you have attached a function to an object.

The debugger won't run on your function because it expects to be passed a variable.

```
function TEST(DISAG) {
```

When you run the debugger, it won't know what "DISAG" refers to.  So when it encounters it in

```
indivDisag = DISAG.localCompare(otherMembers[i])
```

It won't know what to do.

You could include it as a variable within the function TEST(), for debugging purposes.

Comment: Actually, my (first) problem was a typo with localCompare. Now the debugger finds no issue, but when I test the function in the spreadsheet, I get the error `#NUM! The result was not a number`. Any idea about that?

Comment: It's just two typos
(1)   indivDisag = DISAG.localeCompare(otherMembers[i])
(1*)    indivDisag[i] = DISAG.localeCompare(otherMembers[i])

(2)indivDisag.lenght
(2*)indivDisag.length

Comment: Thanks @Niccolo. I now have a result in the spreadsheet. Problem is, I don't have the correct result. I edited the post for further clarification.